# Friend function of Coordinate class for polar-to-rectangular conversion

Tags: c++, class, methods, coordinate-transformation

I have no clue how to do this i've been working on it for hours. There is only one example of friend classes in my textbook.

This is the question"Construct a class named Coord containing two double-precision variables
named xval and yval, used to store the x and y values of a point in rectangular coordinates.
The class methods should include constructor and display methods and a friend function
named convPol(). The convPol() function should accept two double-precision numbers, r
and theta, representing a point in polar coordinates and convert them into rectangular coordinates.
For conversion from polar to rectangular coordinates, use these formulas:
x = r cos(theta)
y = r sin(theta)"

This is what i've come up with but I know i'm doing it wrong I just don't have a good reference point since there's only one lousy example in the whole textbook and is almost completely different. to be more specific I don't know where to use coord&(how to reference the number) and I know I shouldn't have used pointers. Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
//ƒclassƒdeclarationƒsection
void ConvPol(double r,double theta, double& xval, double& yval)
{ 
double x,y;
 xval=r*cos(theta);
 yval=r*sin(theta);
 return;
}

class Coord
{
  //ƒfriendsƒlist
  friend double ConvPol(Coord&);
  private:
  double xval;
  double yval;
  public:

    Coord (double = 0, double = 0);  //ƒconstructor
    void display();
};
//ƒclassƒimplementationƒsection
Coord::Coord(double x, double y)
{
  xval = x;
  yval = y;

}
void Coord::display()
{
cout <<xval<<","<<yval;
  return;
}
//ƒfriendƒimplementations
void time(double, double, double&, double&);

int main()
{ double xval,yval;
  ConvPol(1,5,xval,yval);
  Coord a(xval,yval); 
  a.display();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you have a specific question/problem/error, this is offtopic here and should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, the [tag:r] tag is for the R programming language. Not when you have a variable called R ;-)

Comment: The declaration of `ConvPol`, as a friend in the class `Coord`, does not match the requirements.  Try `friend void ConvPol(Coord& point, double rho, double theta);`

Comment: You don't need the `friend` mechanism for a function like `convPol`; the name `convPol` is not self-descriptive and suffers from the needless-arbitrary-shortening sickness; a coordinate class shouldn't have any "display methods" (how do you decide on the user interface API?). In short this is a low quality assignment, teaching ungood things. Where is it from?

Comment: I'm just confused on using the friend list.  I'm still working on the program. I've got it to do what its supposed to but I was using pointers. @Cheers This question is from a textbook "A first book of c++ by Gary Bronson", used by my college.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are confused.  Here's my understanding:

```
class Coord
{
  friend void ConvPol(Coord& point,
                      double rho, // length
                      double angle);
};

void ConvPol(Coord& point, double rho, double angle)
{
  point.x = rho * cos(angle);  // Assign to the point member x
  point.y = rho * sin(angle);  // Assign to the point member y.
}
```

According to the requirements, the `ConvPol` function converts from polar coordinates (rho, angle) to Cartesian coordinates (x,y).  So, the function needs `rho` and `angle`.

Since the function is free-standing (not in a method), it needs a `Coord` instance to receive the converted values.  It is passed by reference because the parameter will be modified (per the contents of the function).

The function does not return anything, so it has a return type of `void`.

Because the function is a `friend` of `Coord`, the function can access the data members directly as if there wasn't any access rights (like a `struct`).

Comment: Thanks Thomas,  this is very helpful. I'll work on the problem and post back later. This section was roughly 2 pages in my book with only one odd example, again appreciate it.

Comment: This problem was actually not that hard with your explanation. Thank you Thomas, you really cleared things up!!